# Docker - how to call bash command from one container into another from the same host?

Tags: bash, docker, containers, port

I have 2 docker containers running (A and B).

Have a need to call from within container A -> a bash command inside container B.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your B container looks something like this:

`docker run -d --name b_container --rm ubuntu:latest sleep 50000`

and your A container looks something like this:

`docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu:latest sh -c "apt-get update ; apt-get install docker.io -y ; bash"`

you can do (while you're bashed into A):

```
$ env | grep HOSTNAME
HOSTNAME=7d146fa7caac
# # note this is the name for container A
# # and note that the name WONT look exactly like this, but very similar
$ docker exec -it b_container env | grep HOSTNAME
HOSTNAME=668838c220c0
# # and note that you are executing commands in container B and the `HOSTNAME` is different.
$ docker exec -it b_container ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   4372   672 ?        Ss   14:40   0:00 sleep 50000
root        43  0.0  0.1  34420  2800 pts/0    Rs+  14:48   0:00 ps aux
# # and here is how you know for sure that you're really hitting the other container
```

Ps. i don't suggest you do this, you wanted a way... there you are

Comment: Thanks... I will try this soon.. Which way do you suggest? My one container runs Java code and another is Python and want to separate the 2 but want to be able to call Python container to execute something, update database, and then first container can continue.. Can you please share other approaches to achieve this beside calling other container directly?

Comment: @Joe I suggest a queue -- i've also used zeromq in the past to do exactly what you are referring to, but python will have to be "up" to receive the messages. If you want something more detached, i really suggest redis queues with python using rq workers. Essentially: java pushes "work to be done" to a queue, python will be notified right away, pick up the queue item, and do the work. its a tried and tested approach