# Connecting to host network of a docker inside a docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network, localstack

I have a docker-compose stack running multiple images together.

Once i have the docker stack up, I have one local-stack and one mongo running. In Local-stack, if a lambda is to be executed, a new docker image is launched. from the lambda image i need to connect to the mongo image in the existing stack.

The docker.sock access is already provided to local stack so it creates a new docker image in my host machine. now the connection to the network is not established from lambda to mongo. neither by applying loopback address nor by network alias mentioned in the docker-compose.yml

### can you please help me how can i establish connection...?

UPDATE

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.5
    networks:
      apitests:
        aliases:
          - mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    ports:
      - "4567-4583:4567-4583"
      - "4050:4050"
    env_file:
      - localstack-config.list
    volumes:
      - "/tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    networks:
      apitests:
        aliases:
          - localaws

networks:
  apitests: {}
```

My localstack-config.list

```
SERVICES=sqs,sns,lambda,s3
DEBUG=1
DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
PORT_WEB_UI=4050
LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=docker
DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
LAMBDA_REMOTE_DOCKER=false
```

---

Comment: If you want a more precise answer you're going to have to show your `docker-compose.yaml` -- but in the mean time, sharing the volume should be sufficient. See the response i did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990341/docker-how-to-call-bash-command-from-one-container-into-another-from-the-same/48991085#48991085 (hint what you're after is ONLY the volume mapping path)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like local stack had a bug in the code where the newly spawning docker images did not have the access to the local stack network.

There was no provision also to provide any such access as only a temporary image was created on the go.

Enhanced and raised a [PR#883](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/pull/883) for the same.